# Grails Transaction Issues

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, transactions

I have a Grails Service that is marked as transactional and it does a lot of stuff.

I am adding code to this method and not getting results that I expect when I step through it:

1. I have code that calls `.save()` that cannot be seen in the MySQL backend until the whole method finishes. This is what I would expect given that the service method is transactional.
2. I have other code that calls `.save()` that CAN be seen in MySQL before the service method finishes. I don't understand this and I don't understand the disparity between this and 1.
3. I have yet more code that uses the `groovy.sql.Sql` to insert into the database. I am guessing this is outside of Grails transaction processing, so the fact that this commits before the method ends makes sense. Can I get Grails to manage this inside of the transaction?

Please disabuse me of any errors in my assumptions. Here is some relevant code:

**Main Service Method**

```
public void updateDb(Date date) {
        // Create the results
        if (createResults() > 0) {
            createA()
            createB()
        }
}
```

**createA**

```
A a = new a()
a.user = user
a.week = week
a.save()
```

**createB**

```
userWeek = new UserWeek(user: user)
userWeek.number = 1
userWeek.save(flush: true)
```

**createResults**

```
String insert = "insert into ..."
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
sql.execute(insert)
```

I added `flush:true` to make it flush, but I now understand that to just flush hibernate but not actually commit the transaction since it is transactional. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not clear what is happening from the code you post, and it also seems to me that you are breaking conventions. From within one transactional context (the grails method call) you are purposely trying to break out of the transaction?
Also, why are you forcing a flush?

Comment: @HansWesterbeek I wasn't trying to break out of any transaction - I am just looking at code that I inherited and trying to make sense of it. I forced a flush as a test (because I didn't understand it at the time) but I plan to remove that. Nothing (aside from the current `createResults` method that works outside of the transaction) should commit until the full transaction commits, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get `groovy.sql.Sql` running in the transaction that your service method is using by using the [`Sql` constructor that takes a connection argument](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#Sql%28java.sql.Connection%29) instead:

```
  Sql sql = new Sql(sessionFactory.currentSession.connection())
```

This should resolve the problem of data getting committed at different times in the same service method.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation. What solved it for me was calling the refresh()-method. I also tried flush:true and loads of other things but nothing ever worked.

You can read about refresh [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/refresh.html).